# software update problem with problematic raspberry pi code

Tags: package-management

software update spits out the following;

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

openjdk-8-jre-headless: Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.17.1) but 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5 is installed
                        Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1 is installed
openjdk-8-jre-headless:i386: Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.17.1) but 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5 is installed
                             Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.1 is installed
openjdk-8-jre:i386: Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04) but 8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04 is installed
```

Where are the offending files and how does one remove or fix the issue?

Comment: The most common solution is right there in your output: Disable whatever third-party or wrong-version source (repository) that is providing the conflicting packages. Then purge all packages that you installed from that repository.

Comment: Great, but how!?!?! Being a neophyte I need guidance in this.
What procedure, process does one use to find and disable the third-party process?
Same for the packages, I know their name but I don't know how to purge them, how?!?!

Comment: Lesson 1: You CANNOT add random deb packages to your Ubuntu system. The packages you install must be compatible with the existing system. If your system has `Foo 1.0` installed, you cannot install a package that requires `Foo 0.9` nor `Foo 2.0`. Every release of Ubuntu (like 20.04) has a common set of those requirements (dependencies). ALL the packages the require `Foo` use `Foo 1.0`. No exceptions. The reason is simple: Packages are not bolted onto the OS. Instead, the OS is made of those packages. Changing packages changes the OS...and might break it.

Comment: Lesson 2: This *snapshot* method of one-uniform-set-of-dependencies is deliberate: Debian and Ubuntu are supported by volunteers, and there simply are not enough volunteers to test every possible permutation of software packages. So we limit what is allowed. It looks like you added packages that were *incompatible* (not tested, not allowed) with your release of Ubuntu. We don't know what instructions you unwittingly followed that led you down that path. But don't do it again.

Comment: There are many possible ways you could have damaged your system. Each has a different fix. If you could please search your memory and link to whatever instructions you followed, we can help you with a much more specific repair.